# Subgroups containg kernel are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:G\to G'$ be a surjective homomorphism from a group $G$ onto an abelian group $G'$. Show that all subgroups containing the kernel of $f$ must be normal subgroups of $G$.

**Remark:** I know two solutions of this problems. However, the second solution which I came up with does not use the surjectivity of $f$ and I rechecked it many times and everything looks good. Would be greatful for opinion or finding the mistake.

**Proof:** Let $H\leq G$ such that $\text{Ker}f\subset H$. And I am going to use the following fact:

*Fact:* If $H\leq G$ and $\text{Ker}f\subset H$ then $f^{-1}(f(H))=H$.

Using this fact we get that $f^{-1}(f(H))=H$. Let $g\in G$ then $g(\text{Ker}f)g^{-1}\subset gHg^{-1}$ but since kernel is normal in $G$ then $\text{Ker}f\subset gHg^{-1}$. Using the fact one more time we get that $f^{-1}(f(gHg^{-1}))=gHg^{-1}$.

If we show that $f^{-1}(f(gHg^{-1}))=f^{-1}(f(H))$ then we get that $gHg^{-1}=H$  and since $g$ is arbitrary it follows that $H\vartriangleleft G$.

1) If $x\in f^{-1}(f(gHg^{-1}))$ then $f(x)\in f(gHg^{-1})$ then $f(x)=f(ghg^{-1})$
 for some $h\in H$. And since $G'$ is abelian then $f(x)=f(ghg^{-1})=f(g)f(h)f(g^{-1})=f(h)f(g)f(g^{-1})=f(h)$. So $f(x)\in f(H)$ then $x\in f^{-1}(f(H))$. Hence $f^{-1}(f(gHg^{-1}))\subset f^{-1}(f(H))$.

2) If $x\in f^{-1}(f(H))$ then $f(x)\in f(H)$. So $f(x)=f(h)$ where $h\in H$. Then $f(x)=f(g)f(g^{-1})f(h)=f(ghg^{-1})\in f(gHg^{-1})$. Hence $x\in f^{-1}(f(gHg^{-1}))$.

Thus $f^{-1}(f(H))=f^{-1}(f(gHg^{-1}))$ and we are done.

So what's wrong?

Comment: A subgroup of an abelian group is automatically abelian, so surjectivity is not strictly required --- you can always replace $G'$ by $\operatorname{im}f$ and get a surjection.

Comment: @user10354138, so my solution is correct?

Comment: The proof looks fine. It seems like you can do this a lot more easily by using the isomorphism theorems. We have that $G'$ is isomorphic to $G/K$ (where $K$ is the kernel of $f$). And by the correspondence theorem, we have a one-to-one correspondence between subgroups of $G/K$ and subgroups of $G$ which contain $K$, and this correspondence preserves normality. Since $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $K$, there is a corresponding subgroup $N'$ of $G/K$. But $G/K$ is abelian (as it's isomorphic to $G'$), hence $N'$ is normal in $G/K$, hence $N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: @Bungo, thanks for reply! Yes, this was my first solution. But note that here we are using surjectivity. However, in my solution I am not using it at all.

Comment: (Putting it another way, your proof reproduces parts of the correspondence theorem.)

Comment: As @user10354138 points out, you can replace $G'$ with $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ and your proof (and the one in my comment) remain equally valid.

Comment: @Bungo, so am I right that we can throw out the condition of surjectivity?

Comment: Yes, the surjectivity hypothesis is unneeded.

Comment: @Bungo, could you help me with this topic, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002976/theorem-on-abelian-groups-when-the-factor-is-free